# Mysql - search for blogs by tags

Tags: mysql, tags

I'm using the following query to search for blogs that contain certain words in their titles. Each word is recorded as a unique in the table tags and then referenced to an actual blog in the table tags_titles. t.label is where the actual tag words are stored.

For some reason this query does not produce ay results, unless I input a number in which case it produces all the blogs without filtering. How can I get this to work?

```
SELECT tt.blog_id, b.title, COUNT(*) AS total_matches
FROM tags_titles AS tt

INNER JOIN tags AS t
ON tt.tag_id = t.tag_id

LEFT JOIN blogs AS b
ON tt.blog_id=b.blog_id

WHERE t.label IN ('boats','planes')
GROUP BY tt.blog_id
ORDER BY total_matches DESC
```

Comment: maybe you need to use `WHERE t.label LIKE '%boat%' OR t.label LIKE '%plane%'` ?

Comment: I don't want to use LIKE because of the performance loss. These can be exact matches that will be no problem! :)

Comment: What do you mean "unless I input a number".. where are you inserting a number?

Comment: if I use ('1','2') I mean

Comment: can you show us some sample data?

Comment: Added sample data and table structures :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `right join` rather than a `left join` and to fix some other details in the query:

```
SELECT b.blog_id, b.title, COUNT(t.label) AS total_matches
FROM tags_titles tt INNER JOIN
     tags t
     ON tt.tag_id = t.tag_id RIGHT JOIN
     blogs b
     ON tt.blog_id=b.blog_id and
        t.label IN ('boat','plane')
GROUP BY b.blog_id
ORDER BY total_matches DESC;
```

You are asking for something at the blog level.  However, the join is instead keeping all the tags, rather than the blogs.  Once this switches to the blogs, then `total_matches` counts the number of matching tags to get the count (`count(*)` would never return `0` in this case, because there would be no row).

If you want at least one match, then include `having total_matches > 0`.

Comment: this produces all blogs and with total matches as 0, doesn't do any filtering I think :)

Comment: @AmyNeville . . . See the final comment.  Or, change the `right join` to an `inner join`.

Comment: I've added table structures and sample data if it helps